# PowerShell select range of cells from Excel file and convert to CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I want to extract a range of cells from an Excel sheet and output them in CSV form for further use. So far I have written this:

`script.ps1`:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $excel.Workbooks.Open('c:\users\me\desktop\temp\nouveau dossier\superstore.xls')
$WS = $WB.Sheets.Item(1)
$data = $WS.Range("A1", "E10")
$data | select text | Export-Csv 'YATry.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
$excel.Quit()
```

but what I get is this:

```
"Text"  
"Row ID"  
"Order ID"  
"Order Date"  
"Ship Date"  
"Ship Mode"  
"1"  
"CA-2016-152156"  
"2016-11-08"   
"2016-11-11"  
"Second Class"  
"2"  
"CA-2016-152156"  
"2016-11-08"  
"2016-11-11"  
"Second Class"  
"3"  
"CA-2016-138688"  
"2016-06-12"  
"2016-06-16"  
"Second Class"
[...]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in Excel?

Comment: I have been hand copy-pasting the select range of cells into a temp sheet in a new workbook, and then exporting that workbook as *csv, and then opening that file in notepad++ to get to the data. I want to automate the conversion.

Comment: What is the purpose of 'select text' in your code?

Comment: What you have shown us is a  CSV file with only one field.  The name of the field is "Text".  This appears as aheader in the first row..  The next few rows are the names of the column headers in the table you chose in the Excel workbook.  This, presumably, is what you would have expected to see, separated by semicolons,  in the first record of your CSV.  This isn't an answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Select text uses only the values in the range wanted, or else a lot of overhead is included.

Comment: Should you decide to use Visual Basic instead to Powershell for your automation,  there are several web pages that show how to export a range to a csv file in VBA.  I can't evaluate them,  but this one at least has several different methods, depending on your case.  http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2017/09/save-excel-range-data-as-csv-file-through-excel-vba/

Comment: I may end up deleting my answer, as being of such low quality that it won't help future visitors.  I regret the distraction.

Comment: Maybe someone else can build on that. Wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as an alternative method.  I haven't tried this out in your environment, but something similar worked for me.  Hope this helps.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = 
  $excel.Workbooks.Open('c:\users\me\desktop\temp\nouveau dossier\superstore.xls')
$WS = $WB.Sheets.Item(1)
$data = $WS.Range("A1", "E10")
$XLcsv = 6       #  Parameter to tell SaveAs to produce a CSV format
$data.worksheet.SaveAs('c:\users\me\desktop\temp\nouveau dossier\YATry.csv', $XLcsv)
$excel.Quit()
```

SaveAs is a method  in the Excel application that does what the interactive user does by clicking 'Save As'.  The second parameter tells SaveAs what format to generate, in this case CSV.

The tricky part is figuring  out that you have to say $data.worksheet instead of $data in order to gain access to the SaveAs method.

Comment: I get an error because $data is not a workbook per se, and doesn't have the method. This is a PS script, so I'll look into transforming it into a WB first.

Comment: it doesn't work. It says (translated) cant call a method in Null object. Yet, my

Comment: it doesn't work. It says (translated) cant call a method in Null object. Yet, my line: `$data |select value2 | Export-csv 'YA.csv' -notypeinformation -delimiter ';'` still yields a single column of quoted values. I've changed the Range for ("A1:E10") with no difference. I tried copy-pasting to another worksheet and saveas from there, but I got nothing.

Comment: I am sorry.  I said 'workbook' where 'worksheet' would have been correct.  I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: it doesn't respect the range asked, but rather exports the whole sheet.

Comment: It's too bad.  I've reached the end of what I can do.  hopefully, you'll get a better answer from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("d:\Test.xlsx")
$workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Range("A1", "C3") | foreach { $_.Text}
$workbook.close()
```